# Match request method with Kotlin DSL for Spring Security

Tags: spring, kotlin, spring-security, kotlin-dsl

Spring Security provided Kotlin DSL for easier configuration. Here's an example from [Spring Blog](https://spring.io/blog/2020/03/04/spring-tips-kotlin-and-spring-security):

```kotlin
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity?) {
    http {
        httpBasic {}
        authorizeRequests {
            authorize("/greetings/**", hasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"))
            authorize("/**", permitAll)
        }
    }
}
```

I want to allow only POST request to a particular path. In Java, you can do:

```java
http
  .httpBasic().and()
  .authorizeRequests()
    .antMatchers(HttpMethod.POST, "/greetings").hasRole("ADMIN");
```

Any examples using Kotlin DSL?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Asked too early. Seems like I've found the solution after looking through source.

Adding for future reference:

```kotlin
override fun configure(http: HttpSecurity) {
    http {
        csrf { disable() }
        httpBasic {}
        authorizeRequests {
            authorize(AntPathRequestMatcher("/greetings", HttpMethod.POST.name),  hasRole("ADMIN"))
            authorize("/**", denyAll)
        }
    }
}
```